# Filter relationships by a property Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If i create some relationships with properties

```
CREATE (a:A)
CREATE (b:B)
CREATE (a) - [:Thing { thing:1 }] -> (b)
CREATE (a) - [:Thing { thing:2 }] -> (b)
CREATE (a) - [:Thing { thing:3 }] -> (b)
CREATE (a) - [:Thing { thing:4 }] -> (b)
```

**Is there a way of querying them to retrieve a subset of those relationships?**

If I do the following:

```
MATCH (a:A) - [r:Thing] -> (b:B)
where r.thing > 2
return r
```

I get back all 4 of the relationships not just the last two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is correct, and the output is correct (only relationships with thing equal to 3 and 4 are returned).

I think the problem is you're only looking at the graph output instead of the row or text output (look at the view options on the left side of the results), and the auto-complete option in the corner of the graph view is on, showing the remaining relationships even if they aren't in the returned set. If you want the graph view to ONLY show what's returned in the query results, turn auto-complete off.

Comment: Ahh right that's awesome i was getting so confused. So does auto-complete do subsequent queries?

Comment: The auto complete takes whatever nodes are returned by a query, and issues a second query to get all the relationships between any of those nodes.